# Something concerns me about regular expression

Tags: regex, date

I want to match some sub-string like date in month as "21st" or "22nd" or "23rd" in a string, so I made a regular expression using this pattern:

```
((\d{1,2})(st)|(nd)|(rd)|(th)).
```

I made these group because I want to do replace. But when I match some string like "Monday March 21st 2012", it always matches two sub-string: Mo'nd'ay March '21st' 2012.

So I am confused why it matches "Mo'nd'ay"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have a missing set of parenthesis. Try:

```
 ((\d{1,2})((st)|(nd)|(rd)|(th)))
```

What you had, matched:

```
     (\d{1,2})(st)
  OR (nd)
  OR (rd)
  OR (th)
```

Comment: Thanks very much. forgot this parentthesis.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have correct parenthesis around your `|`s. You have `((\d{1,2})(st)|(nd)|(rd)|(th))`, but you should have: `(\d{1,2})(st|nd|rd|th)`.

You're matching the strings `nd`, `rd`, `th`, or (one or two digits followed by `st`).